# markers disappear on map

Tags: openlayers-2

I do not understand why the markers disappear,  zoom 6, only in this area map.

Do you have an idea?

[Map](http://www.mides.fr/test/zoom/)

Answer (score 4):

This is a known issue of OpenLayers, there is a known workaround is to add:

```
renderers: ['Canvas', 'VML']
```

to your vector layer configuration.

I have tested it with firebug in your page. With that line added, it works all right.

The reason is that the default SVG renderer has a limited coordinates range.

For more details please checkout the issue page:
https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/668

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, It looks fine in my browser (IE9). Have you tried using a different browser? Have you tried clearing your browser cache?

Comment: Test with browser IE(9), FF(27) and Chrome(33) and browser cache contents deleted.